# iOS lock Cocoapod/Framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have to develop library for 3rd party. This library have to be secure so that only parties that have credentials can use it.

I am going in a direction that I will provide API key that 3rd party app will have to enter it in order for library to work.

Is there any possibility that I do some sort of locking of a Cocoapod? Or is Framework better solution for this kind of problem?

Does anyone have any other solution/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you elaborated a bit on what exactly you are trying to achieve and what type of task this library performs, maybe give some examples. If I understand you correctly, you need to prevent usage of library by those who did not pay for the service etc.

The key approach will be OK if the library is a client for some webservice. In this case, you should have API keys anyway to protect the API itself, so the client library will just forward this key to the webservice. This approach is widely used in lots of client libraries.

If the library does work only locally (for example, it performs some science-heavy computation / computer vision / etc), then you can just give out the compiled library and license to those who have already paid. You can protect it with a key of course, but it is not too useful, as the key will likely be validated locally, therefore it can easily be compromised or reverse engineered. So the only good way will be to distribute the library to those who purchased / requested trial, and force upon them a license which will restrict the library's usage.

---

**EDIT**

If by "Cocoapod" you mean "distributing as source code" and by "Framework" you mean "distributing as a binary", then it depends on what exactly you do in the library. If it is just connecting to the endpoint and marshalling data (e.g. parsing), you can just distribute the source version, as there is no "know-how" to that. On the other hand, if there is something business-related and specific done besides contacting the API, use closed source distribution (binary).

Source distribution has a benefit that you don't have to recompile it if new target architectures appear. It is also easier to distribute via CocoaPods, and your library users will like it more (for a variety of reasons).

Comment: Yes library will connect to backend API. It will serve for communication between my backend and 3rd party app. Should I create Cocoapod or Framework for this?

Comment: @Matic1911 I have edited my post to answer your question :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!